# I cant install PIP on python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pip

SO when i try to install pip i get this error message any help
i am using python 2.7 because the course uses dependencies from python 2 so ya i cant use python 3 any help is greatly appreciated

```
python get-pip.py
```

this is the command i typed

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
 f:\temp\temp\tmpbwi9va\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:424: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
```

f:\temp\temp\tmpbwi9va\pip.zip\pip_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0